# JQuery code won't exceute

Tags: jquery, html

I was working on an Redirecting page and when i was testing it i seen that 100% of the JQuery code isn't working... so please can anyone help me fixing it ???

```js
var redirect_count = 5;

setTimeout(UpdateCounter, 1000);

function UpdateCounter() {
  if (redirect_count >= 1) {
    redirect_count = redirect_count - 1; // Another Method: redirect_count--;
    document.getElementById("counter").html("Redirecting after <strong>" + redirect_count + " seconds</strong>");
    document.title = "Redirecting after " + redirect_count + "sec - please wait...";
  } else if (redirect_count < 1) {
    window.location.assign("http://example.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>[INFO]: This page has been moved to <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.</p>
<p id="counter">Redirecting after <strong>5 seconds</strong></p>
```

Comment: Where exactly have you used jQuery in your code?

Comment: If you open your console, it says `"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).html is not a function`, since you are chaining your methods, change that to  `$("#counter").html()`

Comment: Including jQuery code is fine... But you are... Eh...

Comment: @PraveenKumar That feel.. yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the whole code to **actually use** jQuery.

```
$("#counter").html(); // This is the right syntax!
```

Including the jQuery library alone **will not make your page awesome**, but you **need to make use of jQuery library** to make it work!

**Full Snippet**

```js
var redirect_count = 5;

setInterval(UpdateCounter, 1000);

function UpdateCounter() {
  if (redirect_count >= 1) {
    redirect_count = redirect_count - 1; // Another Method: redirect_count--;
    $("#counter").html("Redirecting after <strong>" + redirect_count + " seconds</strong>");
    document.title = "Redirecting after " + redirect_count + "sec - please wait...";
  } else if (redirect_count < 1) {
    window.location.assign("http://example.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>[INFO]: This page has been moved to <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.</p>
<p id="counter">Redirecting after <strong>5 seconds</strong></p>
```

Also, you need `setInterval` and not `setTimeout`.

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 22,
  "colno": 5 Edit: that worked after some tests with setInterval :D

Comment: @RedFire Can you refresh and try again? Works fine for me.

Comment: Yes thanks so much and i have answered that it worked before on my last comment Edit :D

Comment: Was waiting for 5 minutes (some timers of Stackoverflow's systems) to be able to tick your answer as accepted :D

Comment: @RedFire Yep... I guessed it.